# How to set SQL_BIG_SELECTS = 1 from VB(legacy ASP) with ADODB environment?

Tags: mysql, asp-classic, adodb

I encountered

> The SELECT would examine more than MAX_JOIN_SIZE rows; check your
>   WHERE and use SET SQL_BIG_SELECTS=1 or SET SQL_MAX_JOIN_SIZE=# if the
>   SELECT is okay

error with my **ASP** code.
ASP code has **server side ADODB connection** with MySQL and connection seems not be able to execute multiple query. How to implement **SQL_BIG_SELECTS = 1** in my code?

```
Set obj_db = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
Session("ConnectionString") =  "dsn=dsn1016189_mysql;uid=apns;pwd=mypassword;DATABASE=mydb;APP=ASP Script;STMT=SET CHARACTER SET SJIS"
obj_db.Open Session("ConnectionString")
Set obj_ret = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Recordset")
obj_ret.CursorLocation = 3
```

and executing SQL...

```
SQL_BIG_SELECTS = 1; SELECT pu.login_id, pu.p_login_id, pu.first_name, pu.last_name, pu.sex, pu.is_admin, pu.attendance, pu.invited, pu.reason, qaa1.answer AS qaa1_answer, COUNT(pu2.p_login_id) AS companion
FROM party_user pu
LEFT OUTER JOIN party_user pu2
ON pu2.p_login_id = pu.login_id
LEFT OUTER JOIN qa_answer qaa1
ON qaa1.login_id = pu.login_id AND qaa1.party_id = pu.party_id AND qaa1.sort_num = '1' WHERE pu.party_id = '92' AND pu.p_login_id = '' GROUP BY pu.login_id, pu.p_login_id, pu.first_name, pu.last_name, pu.sex, pu.is_admin, pu.attendance, pu.reason, qaa1.answer, pu.invited ORDER BY pu.login_id ASC;
```

I can't execute multiple query and above query become error.

```
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'SELECT pu.login_id, pu.p_login_id, pu.first_name, pu.last_name, pu.sex, pu.is_ad' at line 1
```

Answer (score 0):

Sorry I made miss understanding and coding.
It is enough to execute twice SET command and SQL query.

Thanks